# Why doesn't it matter, whether you draw Demand and Supply Curves as arcs, or straight lines?

Tags: supply-and-demand

I read this in an undergraduate economics textbook, but I cannot remember which. Can anyone cite the author, title, and page?

I am paraphrasing, but it counseled that it doesn't matter, whether you draw  Demand and Supply Curves as arcs or straight lines. Why not?

[image]

[image]

[Top](https://open.lib.umn.edu/principleseconomics/chapter/3-3-demand-supply-and-equilibrium), [bottom](https://opened.cuny.edu/courseware/lesson/498/overview) pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn’t matter if you are just demonstrating some simple concept such as shift of demand or supply curve as in pictures above, because as long as the supply and demand are continuous and at monotonic you will get the same result. For example, in the bottom left picture, you will get lower quantity and higher price when supply curve shifts to the left whether the supply is linear or has arbitrary curvature as long as the supply curve is monotonously decreasing.

However, the shape of demand and supply would matter for calculation of exact P and Q, and other reasons. Whoever told you it did not mattered for sure meant it only in context of simple graphical analysis to get idea of direction of new equilibrium.